# A clock table with all items with an effort estimate in Org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

In Emacs' Org-mode how do I make a [clock table](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) that shows all items that has an [Effort estimate](http://orgmode.org/manual/Effort-estimates.html#Effort-estimates) not just those that has [clocked](http://orgmode.org/manual/Clocking-commands.html#Clocking-commands)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Even though not exactly what you want I found this solution in a [mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-02/msg00140.html):

```
#+TITLE: BIRD
#+COLUMNS: %50ITEM(Task) %Effort(Estimated){:} %CLOCKSUM(Clocked) %5TODO(State)

* Effort
#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 2 :id "756fcb74-2e46-4757-82b8-461ed30a5f11"
| Task                                                | Estimated | Clocked | State |
|-----------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------|
| User Stories                                        |     54:00 |    1:24 |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------|
| UI                                                  |        48 |    1:24 | DONE  |
| Remove Company, Street, Place, Country again        |           |    1:24 | DONE  |
|-----------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------|
| Check preconditions                                 |         6 |         |       |
| Check hw preconditions: hard disk, core memory, etc |           |         | DONE  |
#+END:

* User Stories
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       756fcb74-2e46-4757-82b8-461ed30a5f11
  :END:

** DONE UI [11/11]
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Effort:   48
   :END:

The user wants to have a familiar UI. Should look like xxxx,
etc. The user wants to be entertained within his or her monkey time.

[2012-06-25 Mon] Extended: Show every parameter on its own page.

*** DONE Remove Company, Street, Place, Country again
    - State "DONE"       from "OPEN"       [2012-07-17 Tue 09:51]
    - State "OPEN"       from "TODO"       [2012-07-17 Tue 08:27]
    CLOCK: [2012-07-17 Tue 08:27]--[2012-07-17 Tue 09:51] =>  1:24
    [2012-07-16 Mon]

- Am [2012-07-16 Mon] so mit xx besprochen

** Check preconditions [4/4]
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Effort:   6
   :END:

The admin wants only certain user classes in certain circumstances to
be allowed to trigger reinstallations. The admin wants the user to
migrate only clients, that she is logged in into. If the
reinstallation is not allowed, inform the user in an approbiate way
and abort. 

- Check dispersion of load
- Check user class (FF, XX, TT, etc) if allowed to reinstall
- Check if computer is allowed for reinstall 

*** DONE Check hw preconditions: hard disk, core memory, etc
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2012-07-17 Tue 09:21]
    [2012-07-09 Mon]

- Escript periodically retrieves values on client and sets computer property
- user.ps1 check computer property
```

It uses column view in a block that has a column for Effort, Clocked and State. The ID is used to define the subtree, that the column view should capture. You can also specify `global` or what suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:properties` (more info [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html#The-clock-table)).

So, it will be something like that:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :maxlevel 2 :properties ("Effort")
#+END:
```

You'll notice that "Effort" will appear as the first column on the clock table. If that's a problem, you can use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53684091/3670829) (using `:formatter` as well)